# jQuery plugin (or similar) to colour the text Google in the same colour as Google logo

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, target

I am looking for a jQuery plugin or something similar that will change the colour of each letter of the word "Google" to match the colour of the Google logo.

So, for example if I have the following markup:

```
<span>Google AdWords</span>
```

i'd like to change the word `Google` to have each letter coloured in the same colour as the Google logo, blue, red, yellow, blue, yellow, red.

I know this is quite a minor issue, but I would have thought that there would be a version of jQuery Highlight out there where I could target the string "Google", that would do this job but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: -1 i don't think there is a plugin for this.
please ask a specific question and don't let stackoverflow users search for something you want.

Comment: Have you even looked in the source of the page or made a right-click on the word? That is simply a graphic, not written text.

Comment: Maybe this will give you idea [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555995/jquery-each-letter-in-div-element-random-colour-from-array-on-hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555995/jquery-each-letter-in-div-element-random-colour-from-array-on-hover)

Comment: @Imperative Apologies for offending but I spent time looking around for it, but to no avail. I'll happily delete the question if it offends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Css**

```
.blue{color:blue;}
.red{color:red;}
.yellow{color:yellow;}
.green{color:green;}
span{font-size:30px;}
```

**Script**

```
var txt=$('span').text();
txt=txt.replace('Google','<span class="blue">G</span><span class="red">o</span><span class="yellow">o</span><span class="blue">g</span><span class="green">l</span><span class="red">e</span>');

 $('span').html(txt);
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3DRaT/