# Listener in custom jQuery Plugin not firing, using a variable for .on() event

Tags: jquery

I'm spinning an answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555995/jquery-each-letter-in-div-element-random-colour-from-array-on-hover) into a jQuery Plugin, but I'm running in to issues.  I'm using a variable as the event in .on(), but the listener never fires.

**The jQuery**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.randomLetterStyles = function( options ) {

      var settings = $.extend({
          colors: ["#ddd", "#333", "#999", "#bbb"],
          sizes:["12"],
          type:"hover",
          defaultColor: "#999",
          defaultSize: "12"
        }, options );

      //both of these appear in console
      console.log("check 1");
      console.log(settings.type);

        $(this).on(settings.type, function() {
          //this does not appear in console
          console.log("check 2");

          wrapLetters(this);
          $('.random-styles', this).css('color', function(){
              var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.colors.length);
              return settings.colors[idx];
          });
          $('.random-styles', this).css('color', function(){
              var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.sizes.length);
              return settings.sizes[idx];
          });
          $('.random-styles', this).css('font-size', function(){
              var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.sizes.length);
              return settings.sizes[idx];
          });
      }, function(){
          $('.random-styles', this).css({'color':settings.defaultColor, 'font-size':settings.defaultSize});     
  }); 
};


//Recursive function by Logan Smyth
// Wrap every letter in a <span> with .random-color class.
function wrapLetters(el){
  if ($(el).hasClass('random-styles')) return;

  // Go through children, need to make it an array because we modify
  // childNodes inside the loop and things get confused by that.
  $.each($.makeArray(el.childNodes), function(i, node){
    // Recursively wrap things that aren't text.
    if (node.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) return wrapLetters(node);

    // Create new spans for every letter.
    $.each(node.data, function(j, letter){
        var span = $('<span class="random-styles">').text(letter);
        node.parentElement.insertBefore(span[0], node);
    });

        // Remove old non-wrapped text.
        node.parentElement.removeChild(node);
      });
    }
} ( jQuery ));

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#firstBox").randomLetterStyles();
    $("#secondBox").randomLetterStyles();
    $("#thirdBox").randomLetterStyles();
});
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id="firstBox">This box works on hover!</div>
<div id="secondBox">This box works on click!</div>
<div id="thirdBox">This box has custom settings!</div>
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/U78RV/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on('hover', function)` is not like `.hover(function, function)` - it doesn't accept two functions. Remove the second one and the events trigger.

http://jsfiddle.net/U78RV/4/

You can still create those two events

```
$("#firstBox").randomLetterStyles({type: 'mouseover', ...}).randomLetterStyles({type: 'mouseout', ...});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `on()` method with the `hover` syntax as you wrote it. The correct way is like:

```
$(this).hover(function() {}, function() {});
```

This means you have to manually check for valid event types, and handle them accordingly.